# Is there a way to insert two websites side-by-side onto a single one?

Tags: html

Please note, I have no prior programming knowledge. Having not found what I was looking for already made, I've been attempting to create it myself.

I'm trying to insert two websites onto a single website (so that I can decide which I'm going to use depending on my needs). Attempting to have both of them cover half of the screen each, I've tried using the "float" "iframe" and padding tools but without success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WolframDuckGo!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <iframe src="https://duckduckgo.com/" width="500%" height="1000%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
      <iframe src="https://www.wolframalpha.com/" width="500%" height="1000%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected result is a neat homepage with both sites side-by-side...
Result lol https://wolframduck.github.io/

Comment: why width 500%? did you mean to have it 50%?

Comment: DuckDuckGo sets the header `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`, so it is not possible to load it into a frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <title>WolframDuckGo!</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;">
        <iframe src="https://duckduckgo.com/" frameborder="0" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.wolframalpha.com/" frameborder="0" style="width: 50%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

But as @OrangeDog wrote: DuckDuckGo don't load.